# Fundep materialization with implicits loosing type information

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, shapeless

I am trying to use fundep materialization to add compile time safety. The return type of the macro is dependent on the string which is passed into the macro (i.e. the implicit in Foo.scala).

My end goal is a DSL which looks something like this,

```
"Eggs, Bacon".shoppingList.order
```

with methods such as order having implicit parameters using the HList which is generated by the string "Eggs, Bacon" in the macro.

I am seeing some strange behaviour in which,

1. Calling the macro explicitly means I can't call the method on the returned object inline
2. If I rely on the implicit conversion which uses the fundep method, the type is erased and I seem to be casting to types without ever explicitly casting
3. Materializing explicitly and then calling a method is OK.

Foo.scala has the simplified macro and FooExample.scala has the strange behaviour.

Is there anyway to do this?

Foo.scala

```
import shapeless._
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

class Foo[L <:  HList](val list: L) { self =>
  def foo: Foo[L] = self
}

object Foo {
  implicit def materializeFoo[L <: HList](foo: String): Foo[L] = macro FooMacro.materialize_foo_impl[L]
}

object FooMacro {
  def materialize_foo_impl[L <:  HList : c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context)(foo: c.Expr[String]): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    q"""{ new Foo($foo :: HNil) }"""
  }
}
```

FooExample.scala

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.test._

import Foo._

final class Bar[L <: HList](foo: Foo[L]) {
  def bar: L = foo.list
}
object FooExample {

  implicit def foo2Bar[L <: HList](foo: Foo[L]): Bar[L] = new Bar(foo)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val expected = "test" :: HNil
    val notExpected = HNil

    val f1 = Foo.materializeFoo("test")
    sameTyped(expected)(f1.list)

    val f2 = "test".foo
    sameTyped(f2.list)(expected)
    sameTyped(f2.list)(notExpected)

    val l1: String :: HNil = f2.list

    //This actually compiles but throws a ClassCastException
    //val l2: HNil = f2.list

    illTyped("""Foo.materializeFoo("test").list""")

    sameTyped(expected)("test".foo.list)
    sameTyped(notExpected)("test".foo.list)

    sameTyped(expected)(f1.bar)
    illTyped("""Foo.materializeFoo("test").bar""")

    //I actually just want to call "test".foo.bar and have bar have the correct type
  }
}
```

Comment: I managed to get around this currently by using a path dependent type much like the same way Witness and Singleton are done in the shapeless library and adding a method like 'narrow' to convert from my list into the required type.